# In Sitecore, how to Reload the Content Editor with Parent Item on Modal Dialog Ok?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I'm using Sitecore 8. I have custom ModalDialog, it is getting triggered by a button in the Ribbon (Content Editor).

On the Dialog backend, I'm removing the scope Item. So OnOk I want Refresh the Parent and load Parent item on dialog close.

I have the following code but it is not working,

```cs
protected override void OnOK(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {

        //ScopeItem - Current Item in the Content Tree
        //db - Database
        RemoveItem(ScopeItem, db);


        //ScopeItemParent- Current Item's Parent Item
        Context.ClientPage.SendMessage(this, string.Format("item:updated(id={0})", ScopeItemParent.ID));
        Context.ClientPage.SendMessage(this, string.Format("item:refreshchildren(id={0})", ScopeItemParent.ID));
        Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Timer(string.Format("item:load(id={0})", ScopeItemParent.ID), 100);

        base.OnOK(sender, args);
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The normal Delete command does exactly that.  It simply calls `Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Items.Delete()`, which then runs the `uiDeleteItems` client pipeline.  You should be able to do the same by doing something like this:

```
protected override void OnOK(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    //ScopeItem - Current Item in the Content Tree
    Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Items.Delete(new[] { ScopeItem });

    base.OnOK(sender, args);
}
```

Comment: But in my case I want to execute on specific DB, Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Items.Delete not accepting any DB param.

Comment: Can you explain that a bit more?  The item is removed from whatever database it belongs to.  That should be whatever database is the context of the UI (usually master unless you've switched to a different database in Desktop mode).  It doesn't make sense to delete an item from a database that it doesn't belong to in the first place.

Comment: Apart from the good "why" question from Ben -  if you need it from a specific database, you probably need to fetch the item from that database first : something like db.GetItem(ScopeItem.ID). Not sure whether an extra databaseSwitcher would be necessary as well.

Comment: I'm creating the Ribbon (Chuck) >> Command >> Control to delete a item in all others Dbs so that I don't need to do a publish of the parent after a delete.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  But like @Gatogordo wrote, you can just get the items first.  You could probably get the item from each database put them all into the array and pass that to Items.Delete.

Comment: What didn't work?  Did you get an error?  Did it not delete the items?  Not refresh the content editor?

Comment: Two issues. 1. It didn't delete the item in the other DB 2.  It didn't refresh the content tree